# Is there an inverse function for time.gmtime() that parses a UTC tuple to seconds since the epoch?

Tags: python

python's time module seems a little haphazard.  For example, here is a list of methods in there, from the docstring:

```
time() -- return current time in seconds since the Epoch as a float
clock() -- return CPU time since process start as a float
sleep() -- delay for a number of seconds given as a float
gmtime() -- convert seconds since Epoch to UTC tuple
localtime() -- convert seconds since Epoch to local time tuple
asctime() -- convert time tuple to string
ctime() -- convert time in seconds to string
mktime() -- convert local time tuple to seconds since Epoch
strftime() -- convert time tuple to string according to format specification
strptime() -- parse string to time tuple according to format specification
tzset() -- change the local timezone
```

Looking at localtime() and its inverse mktime(), why is there no inverse for gmtime() ?

Bonus questions: what would you name the method ? How would you implement it ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is actually an inverse function, but for some bizarre reason, it's in the [calendar](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html) module: calendar.timegm().  I listed the functions in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79797/how-do-i-convert-local-time-to-utc-in-python#79913).

Comment: calendar.timegm(datetime.datetime.utcnow().utctimetuple()) is the one liner for getting a UTC timestamp.

Comment: Python: batteries included, but sometimes the batteries themselves aren't assembled.

Comment: @erikcw: or just `time.time()` on systems that use Unix epoch (on every system I know). +/- float/int conversion.

Answer (score 4):

I always thought the time and datetime modules were a little incoherent.  Anyways, here's the inverse of mktime

```
import time
def mkgmtime(t):
    """Convert UTC tuple to seconds since Epoch"""
    return time.mktime(t)-time.timezone
```

Comment: Figuring out whether to use time.timezone or time.altzone is the hard part. :-)

Comment: For non-Python people: time.timezone is the non-DST time delta. time.altzone is the DST time delta. To my knowledge, there is no real way to tell whether a timestamp falls on DST, short of calling localtime().

Comment: I second Jester, i general you can't subtract with  timezone  since DST is not in the timezone, this will only get you localtime (without consideration to DST)

Comment: 1. `time.mktime()` expects *local* time unlike `calendar.timegm()` that expects *UTC* time tuple. It may lead to range errors. 2. Some local times are ambiguous or non-existent i.e., either there are two corresponding timestamps or none -- `mktime()` may return a wrong result around DST transitions. 3. `-time.timezone` may be different from [the corresponding utc offset](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3168096/4279) due to DST (`altzone`) or because UTC offset at `t` time was different from the current UTC offset.

Answer (score 1):

mktime documentation is a bit misleading here, there is no meaning saying it's calculated as a local time, rather it's calculating the seconds from Epoch according to the supplied tuple - regardless of your computer locality.

If you do want to do a conversion from a utc_tuple to local time you can do the following:

```
>>> time.ctime(time.time())
'Fri Sep 13 12:40:08 2013'

>>> utc_tuple = time.gmtime()
>>> time.ctime(time.mktime(utc_tuple))
'Fri Sep 13 10:40:11 2013'

>>> time.ctime(time.mktime(utc_tuple) - time.timezone)
'Fri Sep 13 12:40:11 2013'
```

Perhaps a more accurate question would be how to **convert a utc_tuple to a local_tuple**.
I would call it **gm_tuple_to_local_tuple** (I prefer long and descriptive names):

```
>>> time.localtime(time.mktime(utc_tuple) - time.timezone)
time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=9, tm_mday=13, tm_hour=12, tm_min=40, tm_sec=11, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=256, tm_isdst=1)
```

**Validatation:**

```
>>> time.ctime(time.mktime(time.localtime(time.mktime(utc_tuple) - time.timezone)))
'Fri Sep 13 12:40:11 2013'
```

Hope this helps,
ilia.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Demonstration: `assert time.gmtime(10**9) == (2001,9,9, 1,46,40, 6,252,0)`; `assert time.mktime((2001,9,9, 1,46,40, 6,252,0)) == 10**9 - 4*3600` (the last is true only on some systems, of course, depending on the local time zone). Reason: `mktime` does take into account the local time zone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only a newbie to Python, but here's my approach.

```
def mkgmtime(fields):
    now = int(time.time())
    gmt = list(time.gmtime(now))
    gmt[8] = time.localtime(now).tm_isdst
    disp = now - time.mktime(tuple(gmt))
    return disp + time.mktime(fields)
```

There, my proposed name for the function too. :-) It's important to recalculate `disp` every time, in case the daylight-savings value changes or the like. (The conversion back to tuple is required for Jython. CPython doesn't seem to require it.)

This is super ick, because `time.gmtime` sets the DST flag to false, always. I hate the code, though. There's got to be a better way to do it. And there are probably some corner cases that I haven't got, yet.