# Converting days since epoch to seconds since epoch

Tags: javascript, timestamp, time-t

At my new workplace, they represent a lot of dates as "days since epoch" (which I will hereafter call DSE). I'm running into issues in JavaScript converting from DSE to seconds since epoch (UNIX timestamps). Here's my function to do the conversion:

```
function daysToTimestamp(days) {
    return Math.round(+days * 86400);
}
```

By way of example, when I pass in 13878 (expecting that this represents January 1, 2008), I get back 1199059200, not 1199098800 as I expect. Why?

Comment: I don't get why you're rounding. Would you mind explaining?

Comment: Probably because they can use fractional dates too.

Comment: Note: NON-LEAP seconds since epoch. pfranza's comment is true, but not the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 4):

1199059200 represents December 31 2007 in UTC. Sample Python session:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.gmtime(1199059200)
(2007, 12, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 365, 0)
```

Remember that all `time_t` values are against UTC. :-) You have to adjust accordingly to your timezone.

Edit: Since you and I are both in New Zealand, here's how you might have got the 1199098800 value:

```
>>> time.localtime(1199098800)
(2008, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
```

This is so because in New Year (summer in New Zealand), the timezone here is +1300. Do the maths and see. :-)

For January 1 2008 in UTC, add 86400 to 1199059200, and get 1199145600.

```
>>> time.gmtime(1199145600)
(2008, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because it is neither a linear representation of time nor a true representation of UTC (though it is frequently mistaken for both) as the times it represents are UTC but it has no way of representing UTC leap seconds

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Answer (score 1):

Unix times (time_t) are represented in seconds since Jan 1, 1970 not milliseconds.

I imagine what you are seeing is a difference in timezone.  The delta you have is 11 hours, how are you getting the expected value?

Comment: I won't speak for the OP, but chances are good that he's using mktime for that purpose. There's another thread about implementing a mkgmtime on top of mktime, but it's ugly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130074

Answer (score 1):

Because 1199098800/86400 = 13878.4583333333333 (with the 3 repeating forever), not 13878.0.  It gets rounded to 13878.0 since it's being stored as an integer.  If you want to see the difference it makes, try this: .4583333333333*86400 = 39599.99999999712.  Even that makes it slightly incorrect, but this is where the discrepancy comes from, as 1199098800-1199059200=35600.

Answer (score -1):

You should multiply by 86400000

1 day = 24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 milliseconds = 86400000