# Getting computer's UTC offset in Python

Tags: python, timezone, utc

In Python, how do you find what UTC time offset the computer is set to?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`gmtime()` will return the UTC time and `localtime()` will return the local time so subtracting the two should give you the utc offset.

From https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gmtime.html

> The gmtime() function shall convert the time in seconds since the Epoch pointed to by timer into a broken-down time, expressed as Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

So, despite the name `gmttime`, the function returns UTC.

Comment: Subtracting them gives `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'time.struct_time' and 'time.struct_time'`. What did you really mean?

Comment: rakslice, try 
    calendar.timegm(time.gmtime()) - calendar.timegm(time.localtime()))

Comment: @JasonTyler: to avoid races: [`t = localtime(); timegm(t) - timegm(gmtime(mktime(t)))`](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/datetime-sig/2015-September/000955.html)

Comment: @Kirby: [`gmtime()` returns UTC *always*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gmtime.html). There are cases when GMT!=UTC but it is not it.

Comment: naming things is hard, I guess. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: I edited the question to add your clarification which also then enables me to convert my downvote to an upvote ;)

Comment: @Kirby - GMT is a time zone and UTC is a time standard. Also, neither UTC nor GMT ever change for Daylight Saving Time (DST).

(However, some of the countries that use GMT switch to different time zones during their DST period)

Answer (score 109):

[time.timezone](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.timezone):

```
import time

print -time.timezone
```

It prints UTC offset in seconds (to take into account Daylight Saving Time (DST) see [time.altzone](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.altzone):

```
is_dst = time.daylight and time.localtime().tm_isdst > 0
utc_offset = - (time.altzone if is_dst else time.timezone)
```

where utc offset is defined via: "To get local time, add utc offset to utc time."

In Python 3.3+ there is [`tm_gmtoff` attribute](http://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.struct_time) if underlying C library supports it:

```
utc_offset = time.localtime().tm_gmtoff
```

Note: `time.daylight` may give a wrong result in [some edge cases](http://bugs.python.org/issue1647654).

`tm_gmtoff` is used automatically by datetime if it is available on Python 3.3+:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

d = datetime.now(timezone.utc).astimezone()
utc_offset = d.utcoffset() // timedelta(seconds=1)
```

To get the current UTC offset in a way that workarounds the `time.daylight` issue and that works even if `tm_gmtoff` is not available, [@jts's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3168139/4279) to substruct the local and UTC time can be used:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

ts = time.time()
utc_offset = (datetime.fromtimestamp(ts) -
              datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts)).total_seconds()
```

To get UTC offset for past/future dates, `pytz` timezones could be used:

```
from datetime import datetime
from tzlocal import get_localzone # $ pip install tzlocal

tz = get_localzone() # local timezone 
d = datetime.now(tz) # or some other local date 
utc_offset = d.utcoffset().total_seconds()
```

It works during DST transitions, it works for past/future dates even if the local timezone had different UTC offset at the time e.g., Europe/Moscow timezone in 2010-2015 period.

Comment: This is nice and clean.

Comment: Note that `total_seconds()` is available only in Python 3.2+.

Comment: @mattst `total_seconds()` is available in Python 2.7 and [it is easy to emulate it on earlier Python versions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548)

Comment: @JFSebastian Ok and thanks, I checked and you are right. Please note that the [Python 3.3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html?#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) say `total_seconds()` was introduced in 3.2.

Comment: Can't believe Python does not come with `utc2local(...)` and `local2utc(...)`. Glad that @jfs comes to rescue! Upvoted!

Comment: @RayLuo it depends on what you mean exactly. Here's an [implementation for utc2local](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4563272/4279)

Comment: In your first example, why is it necessary to check for DST twice? Shouldn't it be enough to use the output of `time.timezone`?

Comment: @charliesneath: do you mean the second example (with `is_dst`) and `time.daylight`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#timezone-constants

Comment: `datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp` is deprecated in Python 3.12. I think the replacement is to do: `local_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp); utc_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, datetime.timezone.utc); tzdelta = local_time - utc_time.replace(tzinfo=None)` (then call `.total_seconds()` on `tzdelta` if that's what you need).

Comment: @HenrySchreiner it is not applicable here: if you have access to the timezone-aware datetime object that represents local time, then just call its `utcoffset()` method to get the utc offset (like the `get_localzone()` case in the answer but `zoneinfo` is available in stdlib now.

Answer (score 6):

I like:

```
>>> strftime('%z')
'-0700'
```

I tried JTS' answer first, but it gave me the wrong result.  I'm in -0700 now, but it was saying I was in -0800.  But I had to do some conversion before I could get something I could subtract, so maybe the answer was more incomplete than incorrect.

Comment: `'%z'`  is not supported by Python (it may work on some systems where you likely could use `time.localtime().tm_gmtoff` instead, to get the utc offset as a number, not string). The result (of `'%z'`) should be identical with @jts' answer. Include your code if you think otherwise.

Comment: import time

time0 = time.time()
utc_time = time.mktime(time.gmtime(time0))
local_time = time.mktime(time.localtime(time0))
offset = local_time - utc_time
print(offset / (60 * 60))
Gives -8.

Comment: 1. don't put the code in the comments, update your answer instead 2. it is incorrect to use mktime() here, use `calendar.timegm()` or `datetime()` to find the difference

Comment: @dstromberg I think this is the best approach) I like it! My solution was:
`int(datetime.now().astimezone().strftime("%z")[0:3])`

Answer (score 3):

the [time module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/time.html) has a timezone offset, given as an integer in "seconds west of UTC"

```
import time
time.timezone
```

Comment: This doesn't include the daylight savings adjustment

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `datetime` and `dateutil` libraries to get the offset as a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) object:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from dateutil.tz import tzlocal
>>>
>>> # From a datetime object
>>> current_time = datetime.now(tzlocal())
>>> current_time.utcoffset()
datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200)
>>> current_time.dst()
datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600)
>>>
>>> # From a tzlocal object
>>> time_zone = tzlocal()
>>> time_zone.utcoffset(datetime.now())
datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200)
>>> time_zone.dst(datetime.now())
datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600)
>>>
>>> print('Your UTC offset is {:+g}'.format(current_time.utcoffset().total_seconds()/3600))
Your UTC offset is +2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hours_delta = (time.mktime(time.localtime()) - time.mktime(time.gmtime())) / 60 / 60
```

Comment: GMT != UTC. GMT has daylight savings time. UTC does not.

Comment: Actually GMT is the same as UTC.  In the UK we have British Summer Time (BST) for daylight savings.  See, for example, https://greenwichmeantime.com/what-is-gmt/ where it says "GMT (Daylight Saving Time never applies)".

Answer (score 0):

## Create a Unix Timestamp with UTC Corrected Timezone

This simple function will make it easy for you to get the current time from a MySQL/PostgreSQL database `date` object.

```
def timestamp(date='2018-05-01'):
    return int(time.mktime(
        datetime.datetime.strptime( date, "%Y-%m-%d" ).timetuple()
    )) + int(time.strftime('%z')) * 6 * 6
```

#### Example Output

```
>>> timestamp('2018-05-01')
1525132800
>>> timestamp('2018-06-01')
1527811200
```

Answer (score 0):

What did the trick for me was doing:

```py
timezone_offset = (datetime.now(tz(DESIRED_TIMEZONE)).utcoffset().total_seconds()) / 3600
```

This way, I'm able to get the **utc offset** of an **arbitrary timezone** not only the machine's timezone(which can be a VM with a misconfigured timezone)

Answer (score -1):

Here is some python3 code with just datetime and time as imports.  HTH

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import time
>>> def date2iso(thedate):
...     strdate = thedate.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
...     minute = (time.localtime().tm_gmtoff / 60) % 60
...     hour = ((time.localtime().tm_gmtoff / 60) - minute) / 60
...     utcoffset = "%.2d%.2d" %(hour, minute)
...     if utcoffset[0] != '-':
...         utcoffset = '+' + utcoffset
...     return strdate + utcoffset
... 
>>> date2iso(datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()))
'2015-04-06T23:56:30-0400'
```

Answer (score -4):

This works for me:

```
if time.daylight > 0:
        return time.altzone
    else:
        return time.timezone
```

Comment: it is incorrect. Notice: [`time.localtime().tm_isdst > 0` in a similar code in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3168394/4279)

Comment: Sorry, your post is so long and complete that I do not have understood that is the same answer. My post is surely a shorter version of the same solution.

Comment: no, the code is wrong. `time.daylight` does not say whether the summer time is right now. It says that the local time may have DST. That is why you have to call `time.localtime().tm_isdst`