# How can I say to Python to do an instruction at a given time?

Tags: python, time, timezone

I want that a specific time of the day (for example 10:00:00), one of my if condition activates.

For example:

if time is 10:00:00:
print("Hello world")

Imortant: I already read this: [Python script to do something at the same time every day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088037/python-script-to-do-something-at-the-same-time-every-day)

But I don't want to use a function!

Comment: why don't you want to use a function? And you can just have a while True loop, check if it is your desired time, if not, sleep

Comment: A solution can be to have your script ran by crontab.

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh because I have multiple conditions: if x = 3 and time = 10:10:10: do this specified job, how can i do this with a function

Comment: You can do something like this `if datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S") == '10:00:00':` https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/current-time

Comment: you can do the job if time is right, and inside the job check if x is 3

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh you mean this way:                                                                          
import schedule
import time

def job(t):                                                                                                                                                                   
    if x = 3:
        print "I'm working...", t
        return

schedule.every().day.at("01:00").do(job,'It is 01:00')

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(60) # wait one minute

Comment: probably, but the formatting is terrible in a comment, so can't say for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easy use datetime to help you with that.

```
import datetime
from time import sleep

timing = [10, 0, 0] # Hour, minute, second, in 24 hour time

while True: # Repeat forever
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    data = [now.hour, now.minute, now.second]
    if data == timing:
        # Code to be executed
        print("Hello World")
        #######
        sleep(1) # To ensure the command is not repeated again
        # break # Uncomment this if you want to execute the command only once
```

Make sure that I indented it properly, because one space can tick python off :).

The way that it works:
`import datetime` and `from time import sleep` import the necessary modules and functions that you will need.

Modules needed:
`datetime`
`time.sleep`

Now we're set.
`timing = [10,0,0]` sets the time that you want to use (you'll see why later)

`while True` repeats the loop... on and on and on.

`now = datetime.datetime.now()` creates a shortcut for such a long piece of text.

`data == timing` makes sure the time matches the timing you asked.

> Note that the timing is in UTC
> Go to [Getting the correct timezone offset in Python using local timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733139/getting-the-correct-timezone-offset-in-python-using-local-timezone) to know how to find your offset.

An offset of UTC-0200 (Or -7200 seconds) means that you need to ADD 2 hours to your time to get UTC. Or, if your time zone is UTC+0200, SUBSTRACT 2 hours from your time.

Comment: you need to place `sleep` in the loop, otherwise it will run too fast

Answer (score 1):

If you do not one to use a function but need to run a simple script at certain times, you may use [crons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)/job schedulers for this.

[Windows](https://active-directory-wp.com/docs/Usage/How_to_add_a_cron_job_on_Windows/Scheduled_tasks_and_cron_jobs_on_Windows/index.html) and [Linux](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) both supports cron operations.

If you want to do this programmatically instead of relying on operating system tools you need to write a service or a long running process for it.