# Why is there 1 hour difference between gmtime and utcnow datetime?

Tags: python, datetime

If I do:

```
>>> print datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time.gmtime())) - datetime.utcnow()
```

it prints:

```
0:59:59.618000
```

Why would the utcnow() give 4 hours offset from my local time and gmtime() 5 hours?

This prints `-5` and:

```
print int(-time.timezone/60/60)
```

Isn't all this supposed to be UTC time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GMtime has a daylight savings time adjustment part of the year UTC doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

There is no 1 hour difference between `time.gmtime()` and `datetime.utcnow()` in Python. They both represent the *same* time in *UTC* timezone. `time.gmtime()` does not represent time in `Europe/London` timezone. There is no DST transition in UTC timezone. The utc offset in UTC timezone is always zero.

Your code is wrong. It is incorrect to use `time.mktime()` with `time.gmtime()` as an input unless your local timezone is UTC. Your local timezone is not utc as witnessed by `time.timezone != 0`.

> Isn't all this supposed to be UTC time?

- `time.gmtime()` returns UTC time as a time tuple
- `datetime.utcnow()` returns UTC time as a naive `datetime` object
- `time.mktime()` accepts *local* time and returns "seconds since the epoch"
- `datetime.fromtimestamp()` accepts "seconds since the epoch" and returns the *local* time as a naive datetime object

To compare `time.gmtime()` and `datetime.utcnow()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
from datetime import datetime

print(abs(datetime(*time.gmtime()[:6]) - datetime.utcnow()))
# -> 0:00:00.524724
```

The difference is not zero because a time tuple does not store microseconds otherwise both functions return the same time regardless of your local timezone.

If your intent is to find the utc offset of your local timezone then see [Getting computer's utc offset in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3168096/4279).

Answer (score 0):

From the [source](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/7/15/eppur-si-muove/):

> UTC is a timezone without daylight saving time and still a timezone
>   without configuration changes in the past.
>
> Always measure and store time in UTC.
>
> If you need to record where the time was taken, store that separately.
>   Do not store the local time + timezone information!

whereas GMtime has a daylight savings time adjustment