# Python Freezegun giving different values when freezing time to datetime.datetime.now()

Tags: python, datetime, freezegun

Im trying to use freezegun to set the clock back 10 seconds for a unit test.

I've found that setting the time to now with freezegun results in the expected behavior for datetime.datetime.now() but somewhat different behavior for time.time() in that the "frozen" time is ~30,000 seconds behind (8 hours).

Using datetime.datetime.utcnow(), its off by 3600 seconds (1 hour).

What do I need to do to appropriately mock the time to be used with time.time()?

**Using now()**: 8 hours off

```
def test_freezegun(self):
  """ Test that freezegun can set time.time() back 10 seconds. """

  with freezegun.freeze_time(datetime.datetime.now()):
    print time.time()
    print datetime.datetime.now()

  print time.time()
  print datetime.datetime.now()

# Output
[08:09:32] 1436339372
[08:09:32] 2015-07-08 08:09:32.119516
[08:09:32] 1436368172
[08:09:32] 2015-07-08 08:09:32.175031
```

**Using utcnow()**: 1 hour off

```
def test_freezegun(self):
  """ Test that freezegun can set time.time() back 10 seconds. """

  with freezegun.freeze_time(datetime.datetime.utcnow()):
    print time.time()
    print datetime.datetime.now()

  print time.time()
  print datetime.datetime.now()

# Output
[08:08:56] 1436364536
[08:08:56] 2015-07-08 15:08:56.589202
[08:08:56] 1436368136
[08:08:56] 2015-07-08 08:08:56.655346
```

**UPDATE:**

This works, but I'd like to understand why:

**Using utcnow() + 1 hour**:  identical time.time() output, as expected

```
def test_freezegun(self):
  """ Test that freezegun can set time.time() back 10 seconds. """

  with freezegun.freeze_time(datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)):
    print time.time()
    print datetime.datetime.now()

  print time.time()
  print datetime.datetime.now()

#Output
[08:22:27] 1436368947
[08:22:27] 2015-07-08 16:22:27.268315
[08:22:27] 1436368947
[08:22:27] 2015-07-08 08:22:27.339116
```

Comment: The input is interpreted as UTC time. You should get the correct `time.time()` value in `.utcnow()` case. I can't reproduce it using `TZ=America/Los_Angeles` (no 1 hour offset). `freezegun`'s default utc offset for the local timezone is zero (`tz_offset` parameter) for `datetime.now()` method and therefore `.utcnow() == .now()` is expected.

Comment: Unrelated: [`freezegun` uses `-time.timezone` as a utc offset for `time.localtime()` function](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun/blob/a6d4fb6f627ff115302a5d0e00f78b70431d289f/freezegun/api.py#L38).
It is inconsistent i.e., `.utcnow() == .now()` but `gmtime() != localtime()` unless `tz_offset=-time.timezone`.

Anyway, [it is incorrect to use `-time.timezone` as a utc offset unconditionaly e.g., it does not take into account DST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168096/getting-computers-utc-offset-in-python).