# Python make function object subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a function **object** subscriptable in Python. That is, I do not want to create a wrapper class for the function in order to do this.

I'm trying to do this via the follolwing:

```
import types
def func(): pass
def func_getitem(*args): print(args)
func.__getitem__ = types.MethodType(func_getitem, func)
```

If I do:

```
func.__getitem__()
```

It works fine, and prints `(self,)`; but trying:

```
func[0]
```

Raises `TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable`.

The [python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) says:

> object.__getitem__(self, key)
>
> Called to implement evaluation of self[key].

So I'd expect the latter example to work correctly, but it does not.

I originally thought it may have to do with bound and unbound methods, but, unless I am missing something, `types.MethodType` should take care of that.

Comment: I'm just wondering: Why?

Comment: @tyteen4a03 Why put `__getitem__` on a function? For fancy syntax. Why not use a class? I could, but at this point I also want to learn why this way doesn't work.

Comment: Because you're adding the magic method to an instance (the specific function), not the class (of functions generally). See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34443595/3001761. Using a class of your own will be much easier than trying to patch up functions, just implement `__getitem__` and `__call__`.