# Mocking the __call__ method of a class with unittest.mock.patch

Tags: python, mocking, callable-object

I have a class (ClassToBeMocked) that is instantiated in the **init** of another class (ContainerClass).
I would like to mock the instantiated ClassToBeMocked and replace its dunder **call** method.

My code works for regular methods but not for the **call** dunder method.

```
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock, MagicMock

class ClassToBeMocked:
    def __call__(self, x):
            return 42

    def regular_method(self, x):
            return 42

class ContainerClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.runner = ClassToBeMocked()

    def run_a(self):
        return self.runner(x="x")
        
    def run_b(self):
        return self.runner.regular_method(x="x")
    
    
with patch("__main__.ClassToBeMocked") as mock:
    instance = mock.return_value
    instance.__call__ = MagicMock(return_value="Hey")
    instance.regular_method = MagicMock(return_value="Hey")
    
    test = ContainerClass()
    print(test.run_a())
    print(test.run_b())
```

This outputs :

```
<MagicMock name='ClassToBeMocked()()' id='140033866116784'>
Hey
```

While I want to have

```
Hey
Hey
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example below, `instance_cls()` does not call `instance_cls.__call__`. It calls `type(instance_cls).__call__(instance_cls)` as python actually calls the `__call__` method defined on the class, not the instance (for more information check this [answer on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34443595)).

```
>>> class ClassToBeMocked:
...     def __call__(self):
...         return 42
...
>>> instance_cls = ClassToBeMocked()
>>> instance_cls() 
... 42
```

Regarding you example, just change `instance.__call__ = MagicMock(return_value="Hey")`to `instance.__class__.__call__ = MagicMock(return_value="Hey")` and it should work.

Full code below :

```
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock, MagicMock

class ClassToBeMocked:
    def __call__(self, x):
            return 42

    def regular_method(self, x):
            return 42

class ContainerClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.runner = ClassToBeMocked()

    def run_a(self):
        return self.runner(x="x")
        
    def run_b(self):
        return self.runner.regular_method(x="x")
    
    
with patch("__main__.ClassToBeMocked") as mock:
    instance = mock.return_value
    instance.__class__.__call__ = MagicMock(return_value="Hey")
    instance.regular_method = MagicMock(return_value="Hey")
    
    test = ContainerClass()
    print(test.run_a())  # print "Hey"
    print(test.run_b())  # print "Hey"
```