# Convert UTC datetime with timezone to local

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I have a string with a date in UTC and tzinfo

```
"Thu, 01 Oct 2015 00:02:01 +0200"
```

How can I do to convert it to my local time so it outputs

```
"2015-10-02 02:02:01"
```

I tried

```
parser.parse("Thu, 01 Oct 2015 00:02:01 +0200")
```

but I can't find a way to sum this tzinfo to the time to get my local time.

Thanks in advance

Edit: The question is diferent as It includes time diference in the given string and the point is to add or sutract this time diference that sometimes requires to change the date as in the provided example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Convert UTC datetime string to local datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770297/python-convert-utc-datetime-string-to-local-datetime)

Comment: Do you mean  `datetime.strptime(dte, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z").astimezone(tz=None)`?

Comment: @Prune not quite the same, in this case the timezone itself isn't known, only the offset (as a string). It might still be a duplicate, but I don't know where it might be.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham it depends on the platform - Windows doesn't recognize `%z`, although I think they might have fixed that in some version of Python 3.

Comment: @MarkRansom, I think it is good for >= 3.3 but I don' t ever use windows so I could be wrong

Comment: %z doesn't seems to work. 'z' is a bad directive in format 'a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'. It's both a windows and linux plataform script. Python version is 2.7

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: even on Python 3, `astimezone(tz=None)` may fail for past/future dates -- you may need the tz database, to get the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a stdlib solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
from email.utils import parsedate_tz, mktime_tz

timestamp = mktime_tz(parsedate_tz("Thu, 01 Oct 2015 00:02:01 +0200"))
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)) # get local time
```

The input time format is [rfc 5322 time format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.3) that is [understood by `email` module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23117071/4279). `datetime.fromtimestamp()` may fail for past/future dates if it doesn't use a historical time zone database on a given platform. A portable solution is to use `pytz` module, to get access to the tz database:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
from email.utils import parsedate_tz, mktime_tz
import tzlocal # $ pip install tzlocal

local_timezone = tzlocal.get_localzone() # return pytz tzinfo
timestamp = mktime_tz(parsedate_tz("Thu, 01 Oct 2015 00:02:01 +0200"))
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, local_timezone))
```

Comment: The input time format is also compatible with the older [rfc 2822](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822.html#section-3.3) specification, which is what the Python 2.x [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.util.html#module-email.utils) references. Nice portable and succinct answer. +1

Comment: @martineau: rfc 5322 obsoletes 2822

Comment: Yes, I know...was only pointing out why older code written per rfc 2822 also works.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following does what you want by implementing a couple of concrete `tzinfo` classes:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, tzinfo
import time as _time

_ZERO = timedelta(0)
_STDOFFSET = timedelta(seconds=-_time.timezone)
if _time.daylight:
    _DSTOFFSET = timedelta(seconds=-_time.altzone)
else:
    _DSTOFFSET = _STDOFFSET

_DSTDIFF = _DSTOFFSET - _STDOFFSET

class UTC(tzinfo):
    """ Concrete tzinfo time zone class for UTC
    """
    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return _ZERO
    def tzname(self, dt):
        return "UTC"
    def dst(self, dt):
        return _ZERO

UTC = UTC()

class LocalTimezone(tzinfo):
    """ Concrete tzinfo time zone class for current timezone
    """
    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        if self._isdst(dt):
            return _DSTOFFSET
        else:
            return _STDOFFSET

    def dst(self, dt):
        if self._isdst(dt):
            return _DSTDIFF
        else:
            return _ZERO

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return _time.tzname[self._isdst(dt)]

    # everything depends on this private method which assumes 'dt' argument
    # is in local time
    def _isdst(self, dt):
        tt = (dt.year, dt.month, dt.day,
              dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.second,
              dt.weekday(), 0, -1)  # last -1 means dst unknown (mktime will fill in)
        stamp = _time.mktime(tt)  # mktime returns secs
        tt = _time.localtime(stamp)  # localtime returns time_struct with tm_isdst attribute
        return tt.tm_isdst > 0

LOCAL = LocalTimezone()

stamp = 'Thu, 01 Oct 2015 00:02:01 +0200'
dt = datetime(*_time.strptime(' '.join(stamp.split()[:-1]),
                              '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')[:6], tzinfo=UTC)
local_dt = dt.astimezone(LOCAL)
print(local_dt.strftime('%Y-%M-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: ¡Uau! That works defintely but I never imagine that It would be neccesary to much work. I though that could be done in a couple of lines.

Comment: @Pep: `LocalTimezone` that uses [`time.timezone`, `time.daylight` may fail in some edge cases for the current time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3168394/4279) and it definitely may fail for past/future dates if the local utc offset might have been different in the past.

Comment: Yes, a fair amount of code is needed because stock Python only defines an abstract `tzinfo` class. Despite that, what I've provided is an attempt to only enough of a concrete implementation to solve your problem in a generic way using only built-in modules. Alternatives like the [`pytz`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz/) module contains a whole lot more code. The need for so much code is due to the surprising complexity of a seemingly simple but extremely idiomatic practice (which, ironically, has varied over time).

Comment: do you understand that utc offset may be different at different times (unrelated to DST transitions) and therefore `time.timezone` that is a _constant_ can't possibly provide a correct answer in this case?