# Convert email (rfc 2822) date string to another format (ISO 8601 timestamp) in Python 2.7

Tags: python, datetime

I have dates of this format `Thu, 18 Feb 2016 15:33:10 +0200`

and I want them transformed to `2016-02-12 08:39:09.653475`

How can this be achieved with the Python's standard library?

Comment: `datetime` module, `strptime` and `strftime` functions ?

Comment: @Goodies `strptime/strftime` are in `datetime` too - https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior . I was not sure if this solve all problem so I didn't put this as answer.

Comment: related: [Convert UTC datetime with timezone to local](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32897732/4279)

Comment: related: [Converting string to datetime object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26435530/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the `datetime` module as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime

d = 'Thu, 18 Feb 2016 15:33:10 +0200'
datetime.strptime(d, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Or in python2 you may use instead:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse

d = 'Thu, 18 Feb 2016 15:33:10 +0200'
datetime.strftime(parse(d), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

or if need to stick with standard library have a look at J.F.Sebastian's comment at [How to parse dates with -0400 timezone string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101508/how-to-parse-dates-with-0400-timezone-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

check this link [How to print date in a regular format in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-date-in-a-regular-format-in-python/18944849#18944849)

```
import time
import datetime

print "Time in seconds since the epoch: %s" %time.time()
print "Current date and time: " , datetime.datetime.now()
print "Or like this: " ,datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y-%m-%d-%H-%M")


print "Current year: ", datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y")
print "Month of year: ", datetime.date.today().strftime("%B")
print "Week number of the year: ", datetime.date.today().strftime("%W")
print "Weekday of the week: ", datetime.date.today().strftime("%w")
print "Day of year: ", datetime.date.today().strftime("%j")
print "Day of the month : ", datetime.date.today().strftime("%d")
print "Day of week: ", datetime.date.today().strftime("%A")
```

That will print out something like this:

```
Time in seconds since the epoch:    1349271346.46
Current date and time:              2012-10-03 15:35:46.461491
Or like this:                       12-10-03-15-35
Current year:                       2012
Month of year:                      October
Week number of the year:            40
Weekday of the week:                3
Day of year:                        277
Day of the month :                  03
Day of week:                        Wednesday
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse the input date format using only stdlib, you could use `email.utils` package:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> from email.utils import parsedate_tz, mktime_tz
>>> timestamp = mktime_tz(parsedate_tz('Thu, 18 Feb 2016 15:33:10 +0200'))
>>> utc_time = datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(seconds=timestamp)
>>> str(utc_time)
'2016-02-18 13:33:10'
```

where `str(dt)` is equivalent to `dt.isoformat(' ')`.

If you need to support leap seconds; (assuming your platform supports  them) use `tt = time.gmtime(timestamp)` and `time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', tt)`. Note: `time.gmtime()` may have different limits on different platforms (that are probably less than `datetime`'s limits).