# How to parse time.time()?

Tags: python, time

I see how [How can I parse a time string containing milliseconds in it with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698223/how-can-i-parse-a-time-string-containing-milliseconds-in-it-with-python) provides a solution when parsing a full timestamp and [Is there an inverse function for time.gmtime() that parses a UTC tuple to seconds since the epoch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130074/is-there-an-inverse-function-for-time-gmtime-that-parses-a-utc-tuple-to-second) provides a solution when parsing time.gmtime(). How do I parse time.time()? That means, converting it to a time tuple, or something similar with better precision.

I was hoping to preserve microseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [long history](http://bugs.python.org/issue2736) of discussion on the python bug tracker about [round-tripping timestamps](http://bugs.python.org/issue665194). It's probably worth a read, but the quick hack is:

```
In [1]: import datetime, time

In [2]: dt = datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 10, 15, 18, 15, 234567)

In [3]: seconds = time.mktime(dt.timetuple())

In [4]: seconds += (dt.microsecond/1000000.0)

In [5]: seconds
Out[5]: 1328908695.234567

In [6]: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(seconds)
Out[6]: datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 10, 15, 18, 15, 234567)
```

Then, you may just deal with a datetime object which will allow you to parse things properly.

Answer (score 1):

[datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp)