# who can tell me why I use gmtime and mktime in python, get wrong result?

Tags: python

I use python's time module to convert time_struct and timestamp:

```
mktime(gmtime(1404144000))
```

result is :

```
1404115200.0
```

who can tell me why?

Comment: what result do you want ? mktime returns a floating point number, for compatibility with time().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mktime()` is the inverse of `localtime()`, not `gmtime()`

To get the inverse of `gmtime()`, see this question:
[Is there an inverse function for time.gmtime() that parses a UTC tuple to seconds since the epoch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130074/is-there-an-inverse-function-for-time-gmtime-that-parses-a-utc-tuple-to-second)

Answer (score 0):

mktime() takes a time tuple whose value is in localtime. Hence, this will give you the correct answer:

```
mktime(localtime(1404144000))
```

If you wish to operate on a time tuple in UTC, then conversion can be done by specifying the timezone:

```
mktime(gmtime(1404144000))-timezone
```