# Convert to UTC Timestamp

Tags: python, datetime, utc

```
# parses some string into that format.
datetime1 = datetime.strptime(somestring, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")

# gets the seconds from the above date.
timestamp1 = time.mktime(datetime1.timetuple())

# adds milliseconds to the above seconds.
timeInMillis = int(timestamp1) * 1000
```

How do I (at any point in that code) turn the date into UTC format? I've been ploughing through the API for what seems like a century and cannot find anything that I can get working. Can anyone help? It's currently turning it into Eastern time i believe (however I'm in GMT but want UTC).

EDIT: I gave the answer to the guy with the closest to what I finally found out.

```
datetime1 = datetime.strptime(somestring, someformat)
timeInSeconds = calendar.timegm(datetime1.utctimetuple())
timeInMillis = timeInSeconds * 1000
```

:)

Comment: Could you specify what timezone `somestring` in? Is it UTC or the local timezone? `timegm(datetime1.utctimetuple())` won't work if `datetime1` is not in UTC already. `utctimetuple()` does *not* convert it to UTC unless given an aware datetime object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def getDateAndTime(seconds=None):
 """
  Converts seconds since the Epoch to a time tuple expressing UTC.
  When 'seconds' is not passed in, convert the current time instead.
  :Parameters:
      - `seconds`: time in seconds from the epoch.
  :Return:
      Time in UTC format.
"""
return time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", time.gmtime(seconds))`
```

This converts local time to UTC

```
time.mktime(time.localtime(calendar.timegm(utc_time)))
```

http://feihonghsu.blogspot.com/2008/02/converting-from-local-time-to-utc.html

If converting a struct_time to seconds-since-the-epoch is done using mktime, this
conversion is *in local timezone*. There's no way to tell it to use any specific timezone, not even just UTC. The standard 'time' package always assumes that a time is in your local timezone.

Comment: -1: `getDateAndTime()` is unrelated (it accepts `seconds` that the question asks how to get in the first place) and it is broken: the implementation doesn't correspond to its docstring. If you have `utc_time` then it is enough to call `calendar.timegm()` (both localtime, mktime are unnecessary and may produce wrong result).

Answer (score 20):

[`datetime.utcfromtimestamp`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp) is probably what you're looking for:

```
>>> timestamp1 = time.mktime(datetime.now().timetuple())
>>> timestamp1
1256049553.0
>>> datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp1)
datetime.datetime(2009, 10, 20, 14, 39, 13)
```

Comment: Applicable to python 3 only.

Comment: Why is that only applicable to Python 3? It seems to run fine in 2.7.

Comment: A -1 because of `AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'utcfromtimestamp'`

Answer (score 6):

I think you can use the `utcoffset()` method:

```
utc_time = datetime1 - datetime1.utcoffset()
```

The docs give an example of this using the `astimezone()` method [here](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone).

Additionally, if you're going to be dealing with timezones, you might want to look into the [PyTZ library](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) which has lots of helpful tools for converting datetime's into various timezones (including between EST and UTC)

With PyTZ:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

utc = pytz.utc
eastern = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')

# Using datetime1 from the question
datetime1 = datetime.strptime(somestring, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")

# First, tell Python what timezone that string was in (you said Eastern)
eastern_time = eastern.localize(datetime1)

# Then convert it from Eastern to UTC
utc_time = eastern_time.astimezone(utc)
```

Comment: +1 for pytz's localize(). Note: `datetime1` in the question is a naive datetime object i.e., `datetime1.utcoffset()` returns `None` (you can't get UTC time that way).

Answer (score 6):

You probably want one of these two:

```
import time
import datetime

from email.Utils import formatdate

rightnow = time.time()

utc = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(rightnow)
print utc

print formatdate(rightnow)
```

The two outputs look like this

```
2009-10-20 14:46:52.725000
Tue, 20 Oct 2009 14:46:52 -0000
```