# 'ObjectId' object has no attribute 'getTimeStamp'

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to get the timestamp from an ObjectID, but Mongo keeps giving me this error. Am I missing an import? What's the best way to convert the timestamp to a standard date format?

```
video['date'] = video['_id'].getTimeStamp()
```

Comment: FYI, this site demos converting ObjectIds to timestamps: https://steveridout.github.io/mongo-object-time/

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Where'd you see `getTimeStamp()` as a method?

According to the [docs](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/objectid.html#bson.objectid.ObjectId.generation_time) it should just be:

```
video['date'] = video['_id'].generation_time
```

Comment: It's provided in Mongoose (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350642/how-to-get-creation-date-from-object-id-in-mongoose)

Comment: This seems to be a pretty old post, but I figure I'll reply anyway since someone upvoted the above comment (@franzlorenzon). Mongoose is a JAVASCRIPT library, and this question pertains to Python. That is why `getTimeStamp()` does not work in this case.

Answer (score 10):

***this answer is python and Django based.***

Before using `generation_time` be aware that `generation_time` will be **converted to UTC**(Universal Time) which might be ahead or behind depending on your **current timezone**, so you might see a difference in time if you are using your **Local Time** in your project settings to save timestamps on your objects. For me, there is a difference of 5.5 hours. So adjust the time according to your timezone.

**Example:**
For `ObjectId('5c51aca67c76124020edbbaf')` the actuall creation time of this object was `datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 30, 19, 24, 28, 73000)`
but when i geneted its time using `generation_time` it is 5.5 hours behind.

```
In [10]: from bson import ObjectId

In [11]: ObjectId('5c51aca67c76124020edbbaf').generation_time
Out[11]: datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 30, 13, 54, 46, tzinfo=<bson.tz_util.FixedOffset object at 0x102461128>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we get the time in UTC from the object_id of our document, to convert to your local time what you can do is ...

```
document['_id'].generation_time  #(gives the generation/creation time of the object id in UTC.)
utc=document['_id'].generation_time
hours_added = datetime.timedelta(hours = 4)`  #(Suppose utc+4 is my local time.)
local_time=utc+hours_added
```

Comment: That's true, but is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: -1 for that suggestion. You should never do something like that. What if you have summer time and winter time. It will not be right. You should convert using i.e. `astimezone`. Few examples here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770297/convert-utc-datetime-string-to-local-datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770297/convert-utc-datetime-string-to-local-datetime)