# how to get creation date from object id in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I understand from [ObjectId — MongoDB Manual](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs) that the first 4 bytes of any mongodb object id is the creation timestamp.

Any well supported way of extracting that information from mongoose?

Comment: is there a way to filter by date with only _id?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I believe ObjectId has a getTimestamp() method; e.g.

```
_id.getTimestamp()
```

Comment: By the way, the return value is a `Date` object

Comment: is there a way to filter by date with only _id?

Answer (score 12):

You can create a [virtual](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#virtualtype_VirtualType-get) 'created' property on the mongoose schema that uses the _id to get the creation timestamp.
Just add:

```
YourMongooseSchema.virtual('created').get( function () {
  if (this["_created"]) return this["_created"];
  return this["_created"] = this._id.getTimestamp();
});
```

Comment: is there a way to filter by date with only _id?

Answer (score 8):

If you run this you'll get the timeStamp

```
console.log(new mongoose.Types.ObjectId().getTimestamp() );
```

eg.

```
Fri Nov 16 2012 17:20:14 GMT+0000 (GMT)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var timestamp = document._id.toString().substring(0,8);

var date = new Date( parseInt( timestamp, 16 ) * 1000 );
```

Answer (score 3):

For Timestamp

```
 _id.getTimestamp()
```

For the date in ISO format

```
_id.getTimestamp().toISOString()
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be useful **if someone wants to convert the timestamp to a date string**. By using the moment.js library you can easily derive the date from a timestamp.

Example

```
const timestamp = (new mongoose.Types.ObjectId).getTimestamp();

const formatted = moment(timestamp).format('DD MM YYYY, h:mm:ss a');

console.log(formatted);   // output => 09 06 2020, 11:26:27 pm
```

> more ways to format dates in moment.js  
>   https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do the conversion in an aggregate or update query, you can use the [$convert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/) operator and convert `_id` into a `date`.

Example:

```
db.users.updateMany({
    created: {$exists: false},
}, [
    {$set: {created: {$convert: {
        input: '$_id',
        to: 'date',
    }}}}
]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_id.getTimestamp()
```

doesn't work for me but

```
_id.Time()
```

works perfect