# Python: How can I convert a UTC timestamp into python utc datetime?

Tags: python, datetime

- I get the client timestamp as `Wed, 20 Nov 2013 13:53:35 GMT`
- I want to convert this into a python utc timestamp so that I can subtract it and get remaining number of days in month

> ```
> def get_days_left_in_month(from_date):
>         # todo : how to validate if from_date is valid?
>         start_day, end_day = Day.get_start_end_days_for_year_and_month(
>             from_date.year, from_date.month
>         )
>         remaining_days = (end_day - from_date).days
>         return remaining_days if remaining_days == 0 else remaining_days - 1
> ```

How can I do this using python?

Comment: And the many numerous posts here on SO on parsing datetime strings didn't help you?

Comment: apologies but I didn't find the one I am looking for

Comment: I see [135 questions about parsing datetime strings](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%5Bdatetime%5D+parse+is%3Aq), and none helped you?

Comment: Another existing answer using [datetime.strptime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770297/python-convert-utc-datetime-string-to-local-datetime/4771733#4771733)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import time
a = "Wed, 20 Nov 2013 13:53:35 GMT"
time.strptime(a, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
```

And have a look [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) for available formats.