# How to get correct GMT `last_modifed` of AWS S3 key using `boto` API?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

When using get_key and then fetching last_modified property, there is deviation of 3 hours.

```
k = b.get_key('av-bait/modules/reporters.py')
print k.last_modified
```

I get: 'Sat, 17 May 2014 18:42:02 GMT', while the file was updated at 21:42:02 as the following picture indicates:

[image: File as shown in se console]

Any idea how to fetch the gmt via s3?

Thanks

Comment: there is a time zone difference, GMT v GMT +300

Comment: how do I retrieve the GMT +300 via s3 api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to adjust the string by three hours you can use:

```
>>> t='Sat, 17 May 2014 18:42:02 GMT'
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> str_time= datetime.strptime(t,'%a, %d  %B %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')
>>> updated_time= str_time.replace(hour=str_time.hour+3)
>>> print updated_time
2014-05-17 21:42:02
```

There are many  ways to do it, have a look at the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) docs,

Comment: FWIW, the correct date format for the default S3 `last_modified` is: `%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the timezone of your screenshot. The screenshot states the file was modified at `21:42:02 GMT+300` which equals `18:42:02 GMT` so it's in fact the same timestamp and you only need to do some timezone magic to convert it.

Comment: how do I retrieve the GMT +300 via s3 api?

Comment: You can't. This should be a normal `datetime.datetime` object so I suggest for example to follow [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770297/python-convert-utc-datetime-string-to-local-datetime).

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very simple - the timestamp is correct.

Mind the `+03:00:00` at the timestamp on web. If you apply it to the time you see before, you will get exactly the timestamp you get by asking `last_modified`

Comment: how do I retrieve the GMT +300 via s3 api? –

Comment: @omerbach I guess, you are talking about `boto`, and that provides `last_modified` in UTC (GMT). You have to convert it to another timezone using Python, if you need.