# django postgres datetime field to python datetime

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime

I have the following model class

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    sell_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

When I fetch "sell_time" from the model, I am getting datetime in the following format

```
2014-10-01 08:09:46.251563+00:00
```

my question is, if it is not in the format like

```
year-month-day hour:minutes:seconds
```

how can I convert to python datetime object like

```
datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 1, 08, 09, 46, 540535)
```

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you print it? If you print a datetime object, it is serialized to a string but it is a datetime. You can use it as any other datetime.

Comment: My doubt behind the question is I never made a sell at 2014-10-01 8am.

Comment: It's 8am GMT, that might be any other time depending on the time zone you are in.

Comment: is ther any module for converting gmt to ist in python?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770297/python-convert-utc-datetime-string-to-local-datetime

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing that because you did not set the correct time zone. Use the UTC time and then you can format `.strftime("format")` the time accordingly to each locale, you can install `pytz` and enable it in the settings to handle all the hustle. Always use UTC datetime object because then you can get what ever time you want knowing the zone your user is in. [Documentation from Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/)