# Pandas DatetimeIndex from MongoDB ISODate

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime, pandas, time

I am having some difficulty working with times/timezones. I have raw JSON data of the form

```
{
  "Date": "28 Sep 2009 00:00:00",
  ....
}
```

This data is then loaded into MongoDB, and this string representation of the date is transformed into a [JavaScript Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). This conversion to [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) time results in the following date

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("577a788f4439e17afd4e21f7"),
  "Date": ISODate("2009-09-27T23:00:00Z")
}
```

It "looks" as though the date has actually been moved forward a day, I'm assuming (perhaps incorrectly) that this is because my machine is set to [Irish Standard Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Ireland).

I then read this data from MongoDB and use it to create a pandas [DatetimeIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html)

```
idx =  pd.DatetimeIndex([x['Date'] for x in test_docs], freq='D')
```

which gives me

[image]

which is incorrect since the time has not been converted back correctly from UTC to local time. So I followed the solution given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770297/python-convert-utc-datetime-string-to-local-datetime)

```
idx =  pd.DatetimeIndex([x['Date'] for x in test_docs], freq='D')
idx = idx.tz_localize(tz=tz.tzutc())
idx = idx.tz_convert(tz=tz.tzlocal())
frame = DataFrame(test_docs, index=idx)
frame = frame.drop('Date', 1)
```

which gives me the right day back

[image]

I then [normalize](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.normalize.html) the DatetimeIndex so the hours are removed, allowing me to group all entries by day.

```
frame.groupby(idx).sum()
```

At this point, however, something strange happens. The dates end up getting grouped as follows

[image]

but this doesn't reflect the dates in the frame

[image]

Can anyone shed some light on where I might be going wrong?

---

## Response to @ptrj

### Explicitly using my timezone as a string

```
idx =  pd.DatetimeIndex([x['Date'] for x in test_docs], freq='D')
idx = idx.tz_localize(tz=tz.tzutc())
idx = idx.tz_convert(tz='Europe/Dublin')
idx = idx.normalize()
frame = DataFrame(test_docs, index=idx)
...
...
aggregate = frame.groupby(idx).sum()
aggregate.plot()
```

this doesn't work for me, it results in the following plot

[image]

For some reason the groupby is not properly grouping for 2014, as shown below

[image]

If instead, I use

```
idx = idx.tz_convert(tz.gettz('Europe/Dublin'))
```

I get the same problem

### Convert to an object

```
idx =  pd.DatetimeIndex([x['Date'] for x in test_docs], freq='D')
idx = idx.tz_localize(tz=tz.tzutc())
idx = idx.tz_convert(tz=tz.tzlocal())
idx = idx.normalize()
frame = DataFrame(test_docs, index=idx)
aggregate = frame.groupby(idx.astype(object)).sum()
```

This approach seems to work correctly for me

[image]

Comment: Is `idx` a column in `frame` or a separate index? It looks like `idx` is not aligned with `frame.index` (`idx[0]` doesn't match the index in `frame` you pasted - if it's the real data).  If you could paste a small example with `frame` and `idx` that causes this error, it would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it more clear. `idx` is the index of `frame`. I updated the question to reflect this

Comment: Hmm, the error with timezones is strange. I can't reproduce it. Maybe it's another bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the error with the following data:

```
idx0 = pd.date_range('2011-11-11', periods=4)
idx1 = idx0.tz_localize(tz.tzutc())
idx2 = idx1.tz_convert(tz.tzlocal())
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4])

df.groupby(idx2).sum()
Out[20]: 
                           0
1970-01-01 00:00:00-05:00  9
2011-11-10 19:00:00-05:00  1
```

It's a bug deep in the pandas code, related exclusively to `tz.tzlocal()`. It manifests itself also in:

```
idx2.tz_localize(None)
Out[27]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2011-11-10 19:00:00', '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00', '1970-01-01 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

You can use any of the following solutions:

- use explicitly your timezone as a string:

  ```
  idx2 = idx1.tz_convert(tz='Europe/Dublin')
  df.groupby(idx2).sum()
  Out[29]: 
                             0
  2011-11-11 00:00:00+00:00  1
  2011-11-12 00:00:00+00:00  2
  2011-11-13 00:00:00+00:00  3
  2011-11-14 00:00:00+00:00  4
  ```

  or if it doesn't work:

  ```
  idx2 = idx1.tz_convert(tz.gettz('Europe/Dublin'))
  ```
- convert it to an object:

  ```
  df.groupby(idx2.astype(object)).sum()
  Out[32]: 
                             0
  2011-11-10 19:00:00-05:00  1
  2011-11-11 19:00:00-05:00  2
  2011-11-12 19:00:00-05:00  3
  2011-11-13 19:00:00-05:00  4
  ```

Basically, converting to anything else than DatetimeIndex with `tz=tz.local()` should work.

---

**EDIT:** This [bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/13583) has been just fixed on pandas github. The fix will be available in pandas 0.19 release.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get around this for now by changing my `groupby` to the following

```
frame.groupby([pd.DatetimeIndex([x.date() for x in frame.index])]).sum()
```

so where I was originally trying to `groupby`

```
idx =  pd.DatetimeIndex([x['Date'] for x in test_docs], freq='D')
idx = idx.tz_localize(tz=tz.tzutc())
idx = idx.tz_convert(tz=tz.tzlocal())
frame.groupby(idx).sum()
```

I am now calling the `date` method on each element of the index prior to performing the `groupby` operation.

I'm posting this as an answer in case nobody replies, but I am hoping for someone to answer and *explain* what is happening, as my 'solution' seems too hacky for my tastes.