# Easy way to convert UTC to another timezone in python

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

I'm trying to convert a UNIX time stamp to UTC+9. I've been searching for hours and it's all very confusing what with the different libraries etc

Here's what I've got so far

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
import datetime

time = 1481079600
utc_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time)#.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print utc_time.strftime(fmt)

tz = timezone('Japan')
print tz.localize(utc_time).strftime(fmt)
```

This just prints the same time, what am I doing wrong

Comment: See the answers here for more insights: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770297/python-convert-utc-datetime-string-to-local-datetime/46339491#46339491

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to shamelessly plug this new `datetime` library I am obsessed with, Pendulum.

```
pip install pendulum

import pendulum

t = 1481079600

pendulum.from_timestamp(t).to_datetime_string()
>>> '2016-12-07 03:00:00'
```

And now to change it to your timezone super quick and easy!

```
pendulum.from_timestamp(t, 'Asia/Tokyo').to_datetime_string()
>>> '2016-12-07 12:00:00'
```

Comment: 2 lines of code perfect, i need to improve my google foo, I couldn't find a simple solution anywhere

Comment: It's a relatively new library, but it is amazing and I prefer it to the native Python one. Here is the documentation for all the cool things it can do. https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Your `utc_time` datetime is naive - it has no timezone associated with it. `localize` assigns a timezone to it, it doesn't convert between timezones. The simplest way to do that is probably to construct a timezone-aware datetime:

```
import pytz
utc_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time, pytz.utc)
```

Then convert to the timezone you want when you're ready to display it:

```
print utc_time.astimezone(tz).strftime(fmt)
```

Comment: where 'tz' comes from where?

Comment: Well, in this example it comes from `tz = timezone('Japan')` in the question. You do of course have to know what time zone you want to localize to.