# Convert time from UTC to GMT with Python

Tags: python, datetime, utc, gmt

I'm writting a python app that convert YML files to static HTML pages for my blog (static site generator). I want to add an RSS feed. On a some place I read that the publication date must be:

```
<pubDate>Wed, 05 Jul 2017 18:38:23 GMT</pubDate>
```

But I have:

```
<pubDate>2017-07-05T18:38:23+00:00</pubDate>
```

The `datetime` API from Python is really cumbersome about these. How to convert the string `2017-07-05T18:38:23+00:00` to GMT?

Thanks in avanced.

Comment: http://strftime.org/

Comment: i always user [arrow](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to deal with date time in python, its fairly easy to use

Comment: Just write a regex or somehow convert the string before converting.

Comment: You might find this helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770297/python-convert-utc-datetime-string-to-local-datetime

Comment: @SalmaanP Good tip and nice reference. You can probably add an answer with the arrow library code snippet.

Comment: @araknoid didn't think it was worthy of an answer but wrote it now anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import datetime
basedate="2017-07-05T18:38:23+00:00"
formatfrom="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00"
formatto="%a %d %b %Y, %H:%M:%S GMT"
print datetime.datetime.strptime(basedate,formatfrom).strftime(formatto)
```

will return you the correct transcription : Wed 05 Jul 2017, 18:38:23 GMT

my source for the formats : http://strftime.org/

Comment: I would have used the time module (import time) instead of the datetime module  but, I think the gist is the same.  up vote.

Answer (score 5):

While the other answers are correct, I always use [arrow](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to deal with date time in python, it's very easy to use.

For you example, you can simply do

```
import arrow
utc = arrow.utcnow()
local = utc.to('US/Pacific')
local.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss ZZ')
```

The doc contains more information.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest using [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which is a really powerful extension to datetime. It has a robust parser, that enables parsing any input format of datetime to a datetime object. Then you can reformat it to your desired output format.

This should answer your need:

```
from dateutil import parser

original_date = parser.parse("2017-07-05T18:38:23+00:00")
required_date = original_date.strftime("%a %d %b %Y, %H:%M:%S GMT")
```

Comment: I get an error when I try with your code: "NameError: global name 'parser' is not defined". Something missed?

Comment: You are right. Sorry. I fixed the imports in my answer (`from dateutil import parser`). The rest stays the same