# Get timezone local time from UTC time: arrow vs pendulum vs pytz

Tags: python, date, datetime, timezone, dst

How to convert `s = "2018-03-17T15:30:00.000Z"` to Paris local time?

I've seen solutions involving:

- arrow:

  ```
  import arrow
  print(arrow.get("2018-03-17T15:30:00.000Z").to('Europe/Paris').datetime)
  ```

  but [some posts](http://blog.eustace.io/please-stop-using-arrow.html) mention it to be not maintained anymore
- pendulum:

  ```
  import pendulum
  print(pendulum.parse("2018-03-17T15:30:00.000Z"))
  ```

  (seems [faster](https://pendulum.eustace.io/blog/a-faster-alternative-to-pyz.html) than pytz)
- [pytz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz) is often cited as a reference because it uses a popular timezone database (Olson timezone database?)

**What is a production-ready way to convert UTC datetimes to local time, with a well maintained world timezone/DST database?** (I learnt recently that these things change often at least in some places of the world)

Comment: [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
Requesting an off-site resource is specifically proscribed.

Comment: @Prune An off-site resource? What distinguishes Python from pytz? They are both off-site tools (one is a programming language, the other one is a library, but still they are off-site). Then are Python questions questions involving off-site resources?

Comment: You're asking for a package well-maintained data base, no?  That's my sticking point.

Comment: @Prune Well I'm just looking for a solution for a specific task (convert UTC time to local time-zone, in an accurate way).

Comment: None of the prior postings or resources cover all the cases for you?  For [instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770297/convert-utc-datetime-string-to-local-datetime-with-python) ... ?

Comment: I already read this question @Prune but it doesn't cover the particular comparison between mentioned libraries.

Comment: You seem to already have an answer with pendulum or pytz.  Also dateutil.  So it seems you are only asking for opinions.