# How to convert time in this format to local time zone?

Tags: python, datetime-format, time-format

I'd like to convert this time `Sat, 19 May 2018 16:32:56 +0000` to `20180519-113256` in a local timezone (EDT in this example) in python. Could anybody show me how to do it?

PS., The following example shows how to convert time to local timezone. But I am not sure how to parse `Sat, 19 May 2018 16:32:56 +0000`.

[Convert UTC datetime string to local datetime with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770297)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

Answer (score 1):

You could choose any timezone you want:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

s = 'Sat, 19 May 2018 16:32:56 +0000'
dt = datetime.strptime(s, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
tz = pytz.timezone('America/Chicago')
new_s = dt.astimezone(tz).strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

for me this works:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz

def convert(date, from_zone = 'UTC', to_zone='America/New_York'):
    from_zone = tz.gettz(from_zone)
    to_zone = tz.gettz(to_zone)
    date = date.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
    central = date.astimezone(to_zone)
    return date

s = "Sat, 19 May 2018 16:32:56 +0000"
d = datetime.strptime(s, '%a, %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S +%f')
d = convert(d)
```