# How to convert Django model DateTimeField into local timezone and use Q object to filter

Tags: python, django

How to convert db DateTime field into local time and construct Q object for retrieving the dataset?

settings.py

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
USER_TIME_ZONE = 'US/Pacific'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_TZ = True
```

models.py

```
class Hello(models.Model):

  lucky_day = models.DateTimeField()
```

One record in db (UTC format)

```
2019-02-03 03:02:45
```

filter.py

```
# Client browser is Pacific time without time, date only.
localtime_str = '2019-3-2' 

qset_filter = Q(lucky_day<to Pacific time from UTC>=localtime_str)
```

Comment: Why don't you convert the local time to UTC in Python rather than mucking around in the database (where the conversion of the db data would need to take place for filtering to work)?

Comment: That's not what I wanted as local time string has no time. Comparison will be invalid after conversion with db UTC time with time. I just want to compare date. Thanks.

Comment: Then look into the timezone conversion functions of your database and custom [Func](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) expressions to harness them.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to first convert a utc datetime field to local datetime and then you want to filter based on localdatetime, you can use django aggregation to do that in this way:

```
YourModel.objects.annotate(new_local_datetime_field=convert_to_local_datetime('lucky_day')).filter(Q(new_local_datetime_field=some_other_datetime))
```

Reference to convert utc datetime to local datetime:
[Convert UTC datetime string to local datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770297/convert-utc-datetime-string-to-local-datetime)

reference to django annotation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate

Comment: Where is `convert_to_local_datetime` defined?

Comment: I have same question. How to implement convert_to_local_datetime?

Comment: you can find here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770297/convert-utc-datetime-string-to-local-datetime

Comment: @VedprakashUpraity those methods don't work on database level