# how to convert a column of data in GMT format to local time in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have to plot a column of data,but it is given in GMT format in python.I need to convert it into local time.
I tried different codes given in this site for converting, but none of these worked

Comment: I think the question duplicates this one:
[Convert UTC datetime string to local datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770297/convert-utc-datetime-string-to-local-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

First step is to parse it into a proper datetime object:

```py
import datetime

column_date_str_gmt = ...
gmt_datetime = datetime.datetime.strftime(column_date_str_gmt, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

Then, move the gmt datetime over to UTC:

```py
from datetime import timezone

utc_datetime= gmt_datetime.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()
```

Finally, convert to local time:

```py
import time

epoch = time.mktime(utc.timetuple())
epoch_offset = datetime.fromtimestamp (epoch) - datetime.utcfromtimestamp (epoch)
local_datetime = utc + epoch_offset
```

Comment: ,when i give the column name to the variable "column_date_str_gmt",it shows error.

Comment: Can you paste the error? the variable `column_date_str_gmt` is expecting a string value from your original dataset.

Comment: File "<ipython-input-253-7fe88e9ebf55>", line 4, in <module>
    gmt_datetime = datetime.datetime.strftime(column_date_str_gmt, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: That means that you need to index the array to extract out your GTM column. Something like `myArray[2]`

Comment: I am a beginner in python so I am confused about this.I took the data from excel using pandas which is stored in a variable 'b' and its of type numpy.ndarray.What should I do to this 'b' to make it local time