# convert str date to datetime for timezone

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format

I have an API that return this date string

```
strdate = '2019-10-07T06:09:28.984Z'
```

How do I convert it to a datetime object?

```
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(strdate, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

If I use strptime like above i get "ValueError: unconverted data remains: T06:09:54.346Z"
What do I do if there is "T" and "Z" included in the string date? I want the data in local time. But is the string really timezone aware so I can convert it properly? In this case I know the timezone, but what if I did not know?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert UTC datetime string to local datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770297/convert-utc-datetime-string-to-local-datetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you're not including the time part in the format string. Do that:

```
datetime.strptime('2019-10-07T06:09:28.984Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
```

This results in:

```
datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 7, 6, 9, 28, 984000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

If you want to convert this to a local timezone, do that:

```
from pytz import timezone

dt = datetime.strptime(strdate, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
local_dt = dt.astimezone(timezone('Asia/Tokyo'))
```

Demo: https://repl.it/repls/RotatingSqueakyCertifications

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
strdate = '2019-10-07T06:09:28.984Z'
dt=datetime.datetime.strptime(strdate, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
print(dt)

# output - 2019-10-07 06:09:28.984000
```