# Removing part of a datetime value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I have a column such as

```
  time
1508089361
1508065388
1508011482
```

I want to convert this to a local timestamp setting the timezone for a particular region, so I use the code below:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s').dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Europe/Berlin')
```

It returns me a column with values as below:

```
          time
2017-10-04 16:17:34+02:00   
2017-10-04 14:17:34+02:00   
2017-10-04 08:17:34+02:00
```

IS there any way can I remove the +02:00 so I can just have a normal timestamp?
the column type is a datetime64[ns, Europe/Berlin]

I want to join two dfs on these times but cannot since the other df has these times already in normal datetime timestamp format such as:

```
       Time
2017-10-09 00:00:00
2017-10-09 00:00:00
2017-10-09 00:00:00
2017-10-09 00:00:00
```

Thanks!

Comment: Stop at the UTC?

Comment: But I need it in local time of that region or city @thebjorn

Comment: "Normal datetime timestamp format" would be UTC (you'll likely save yourself lots of headaches if you convert everything to UTC first). If you absolutely want localtime, then this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770297/convert-utc-datetime-string-to-local-datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Please use this function

```
dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

More details on formatting https://strftime.org/

Comment: But this does not account for localizing the time to the region above?

Comment: got it so can convert as above , then reformat as this

Comment: yep, you can do it this way