# How to print a datetime as UTC string

Tags: python

I have something like

```
from dateutil import parser
my_datetime = parser.parse("2020-06-19 12:10:10.12345+02")
```

I want to print this as 2020-06-19 10:10:10.12345Z

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert UTC datetime string to local datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770297/convert-utc-datetime-string-to-local-datetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dateutil.tz` to access timezones and then express a given date with that timezone with `.astimezone()`.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
from dateutil.tz import tzutc

my_datetime = parse("2020-06-19 12:10:10.12345+02")

print(my_datetime.astimezone(tzutc()))
```