# How to get time in specific timezone in telethon event handler

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am using the telethon library to making telegram bots.
when I using `event.date` it was printing the time on +00.00 time zone.
How can I print time on specific timezone

Comment: maybe you should use standard module `datetime` to convert  it to other timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.now().isoformat(timespec='minutes'))
```

have a look in [datetime library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

Answer (score 3):

See [python - Convert UTC datetime string to local datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4770297/). Stealing the top answer which uses `python-dateutil`:

```py
from dateutil import tz
local_datetime = event.date.astimezone(tz.tzlocal())
```