# How to convert UTC datetime to local datetime (Australia/Melbourne) in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, timezone, python-datetime

I have a data frame with "Date" column in UTC format.

```
Date
2021-10-14T06:57:00.000+0000
2021-09-05T08:30:00.000+0000
2021-10-20T04:34:00.000+0000
2021-10-19T21:49:00.000+0000
2021-09-30T20:53:00.000+0000
```

Tried this but didnt work;

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].substr(replace(to_iso8601(from_iso8601_timestamp(Date) AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Melbourne'), 'T', ' '), 1, 16) Date_local
```

I am unable to converte the UTC time to the local time zone (Australia/Melbourne).

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert UTC datetime string to local datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770297/convert-utc-datetime-string-to-local-datetime)

Comment: i tried but didnt work for me. not sure where I am going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use pandas functionality; [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then [tz_convert](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html).

```
# input strings to datetime data type:
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# UTC is already set (aware datetime); just convert:
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.tz_convert('Australia/Melbourne')

df['Date']
Out[2]: 
0   2021-10-14 17:57:00+11:00
1   2021-09-05 18:30:00+10:00
2   2021-10-20 15:34:00+11:00
3   2021-10-20 08:49:00+11:00
4   2021-10-01 06:53:00+10:00
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns, Australia/Melbourne]
```