# How to convert a naive time to UTC time in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime, time

How can I change this naive time to UTC time in python

The time is `2021-08-05T08:32:47.362000Z`

```
st= "2021-08-05T08:32:47.362000Z"

dt = datetime.strptime(st,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

I don't know how to parse this time in python. The above given code is what I know I don't know to parse this time.

So this time has been fetched from Django database and what I inserted is a UTC time and I got the above time as a result.

The thing is I need to get utc time.

Comment: This has already been answered in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595047/convert-to-utc-timestamp

Comment: It also has been answered for [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68664644/10197418) (except for the 'T' in the date/time string).

Comment: basically a duplicate of [how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Comment: Please clarify in how [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68664644/how-can-i-convert-from-utc-time-to-local-time-in-python) does not cover this one as well. From the looks of it, the only "issue" is replacing a space with a T in the expected format.