# How to convert dates to UTC taking into account winter and summer time?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, utc

My objective is to convert a list of dates to the correct UTC format, i.e.: taking into consideration winter and summer time. Dates were scrapped from a chat.

I am Switzerland based which uses (CET) UTC+01:00 during the winter and (CEST) Central European Summer Time during the summer i.e. UTC+02:00.

Here are the dates:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['dates_raw'] = [
    '2022-01-20 01:12:15',
    '2022-06-22 12:00:00',
    '2022-10-29 05:57:02',
    '2022-12-18 09:34:17',
    '2023-01-12 06:36:10',
    '2023-02-17 20:23:10',
    '2023-04-12 02:02:24',
    '2023-09-12 15:57:35',]
```

And here the desired result:

```
df['dates_converted'] = [
    '2022-01-20 00:12:15',
    '2022-06-22 10:00:00',
    '2022-10-29 03:57:02',
    '2022-12-18 08:34:17',
    '2023-01-12 05:36:10',
    '2023-02-17 19:23:10',
    '2023-04-12 00:02:24',
    '2023-09-12 13:57:35',]
```

And finally, here are the dates changes from summer to winter to summer... etc. etc.:

```
dates_changes = {
    'st_2022' : '2022-03-27 02:00:00', # UTC + 2 (we gain one hour)
    'wt_2022' : '2022-10-30 03:00:00', # UTC + 1 (we loose one hour)
    'st_2023' : '2023-03-26 02:00:00', # UTC + 2 (we gain one hour)
    'wt_2023' : '2023-10-29 03:00:00', # UTC + 1 (we loose one hour)
    'st_2024' : '2024-03-31 02:00:00', # UTC + 2
    'wt_2024' : '2024-10-27 03:00:00', # UTC + 1
    }
```

As the dates changes look arbitrary, I don't know if there is any built-in function to make the conversion.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess parts of the answer could be found under [Convert to UTC Timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1595195/6771046) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by first using `pd.to_datetime` to convert the strings to naive datetimes, then `tz_localize` to interpret those naive datetimes as aware datetimes in your desired timezone, and finally `tz_convert` to convert to UTC.

```
df['dates_converted'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates_raw']).dt.tz_localize('Europe/Zurich').dt.tz_convert('UTC')
print(df['dates_converted'])
```

result:

```
0   2022-01-20 00:12:15+00:00
1   2022-06-22 10:00:00+00:00
2   2022-10-29 03:57:02+00:00
3   2022-12-18 08:34:17+00:00
4   2023-01-12 05:36:10+00:00
5   2023-02-17 19:23:10+00:00
6   2023-04-12 00:02:24+00:00
7   2023-09-12 13:57:35+00:00
Name: dates_converted, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

This code as it stands will give an exception with some ambiguous datetimes. For example, what is `2022-10-30 02:30:00`? Is it 00:30 UTC or 01:30 UTC? - you can't tell. If your data contains such times, you can handle it by passing the `ambiguous` arg to `tz_localize`: check the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_localize.html) for the options here and choose the one that will best deal with your data.

Comment: Many thanks! How would you do the same tz_localize function to a single date (in datetime format) to convert it ?

Comment: Do you mean you have a single string in a format like `'2022-01-20 00:12:15'`? Or a single datetime object?

Comment: Yes, a datetime object, sorry !

Comment: Cool, so assuming `my_dt` is a naive datetime object that represents a time in Swiss timezone, then I'd avoid Pandas functions and do: `my_dt.replace(tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('Europe/Zurich')).astimezone(zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('UTC'))` (This requires `import zoneinfo`)