# migrating mysql datetime fields from django 1.3 to django 1.4

Tags: mysql, django, timezone

In my `settings.py` I use `America/Chicago` as my default `TIME_ZONE` variable. I am going to update to django 1.4 soon. As a MySql user, I would like to know if there is anything I need to know before the upgrade.

The reason for upgrading to 1.4 is, of course, the timezone support that django 1.4 offers and it is very essential to what I am doing at the moment. I noticed that MySQL timestamp objects are not in UTC format (my models all use `DateTimeField()`).

What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

I am dealing with this upgrade now and unfortunately there isn't a clear path to follow. The django 1.4 migration guide instructs that the values in the database need to be converted but that [this isn't possible deterministically](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#other-databases)!

So you will have to convert the values but know that in some cases around daylight savings time transitions the conversion will not be perfect. I plan to use the new [make_aware(value, timezone)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.make_aware) function in django 1.4 to convert the datetime values and I will handle the exceptions by retrying the conversion after adding an hour to the input datetime.

Here are [specific details and lots more sample code for converting local time to UTC in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79797/how-do-i-convert-local-time-to-utc-in-python)

Comment: Thank you. I already manage to do the upgrade. It took my some days because some modules (like django-notification or django-avatar, or even South) needed modifications/updates, too. I also had some problems using the new template timezone filters so I wrote mine. In my template filter I also use a method similar to the one you suggest. I found make_aware() and make_naive() to be very usefull. To sum up the migration was not very easy. It took me some time. I had to make some changes in the model, too.