# How to split the date in data preprocessing step in python and keep the format of the date in float?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I am unable to change the date into the float format. When I use them I get the following error.

> return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order) ValueError: could not
>   convert string to float: '24/03/2019'

Comment: don't change a string to float format. you may convert it into datetime format. you can get a sense from this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: Any code example?

Comment: @JithinPal the link has code examples if you scroll down.

Comment: I think you need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24590666/2901002)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't parse a string like `24/03/2019` info a `float/int` since it has non numeric `chars`.

My advice would be to parse that string date into a datetime:

```py
from datetime import datetime

# without time
datetime_obj = datetime.strptime('24/03/2019', '%d/%m/%Y')
print(datetime_obj.date())

# with time
date_time_str = '2018-06-29 08:15:27.243860'  
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-03-24 08:15:27.243860', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
print(datetime_obj.date())
```

If you really need to parse it into a numeric value and the dates are all like the one you provided, `24/03/2019`, I would advise to use a regex and parse it into an int instead of float.

Comment: What will be the type of the data after the process you suggested?

Comment: It would be a `datetime` object.

If you want to know more about what you could do with this type of object check https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: After converting them, how to split them into different columns, can it be done with the help of split() ?

Comment: If you have it in a `datetime` object you don't need to split anything.
For example if you want the year: `date_obj.year`