# Python - convert naive datetime to UTC

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, odoo

I have date that I get in specific timezone time, but system deals with it as UTC and later it converts it back in that timezone, messing time.

For example like this:

I get this time: `2014-05-05 10:50:30`. its datetime object. It has no timezone info, but I can get timezone info from user that uses that time. The thing is this time is showed as 'Europe/Vilnius' time, but system deals with it as UTC and when it outputs time to user it adds +3 hours showing wrong time. It does not matter if I change timezone to users timezone on that datetime object, it still outputs with +3 hours.

For example (snippet of code):

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz         
create_date = datetime.strptime(stage_log.create_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
tz = pytz.timezone(self.user_id.tz)
create_date = create_date.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
```

This does not do anything and I still get wrong time.

Is there a way to move time to be correct UTC time(so then system correctly convert to users timezone) like this:

`2014-05-05 10:50:30` -> convert to UTC. If timezone is 'Europe/Vilnius', it should convert that time to `2014-05-05 07:50:30`. Then when system automatically does conversions it would correctly display `2014-05-05 10:50:30`, because thats the time it should display.

Also if there is a way to just get number of hours that given timezone differs from UTC, then I could just do as simple as that:

`create_date.replace(hour=create_date.hour-timezone_difference)`

Comment: This one saved the day - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79797/how-do-i-convert-local-time-to-utc-in-python

Answer (score 2):

While this question does not specifically reference odoo, hopefully the following may help others:

Odoo - convert datetime to UTC:
(note: in this example self.start_date is a fields.Date)

```
start_date = fields.Datetime.to_string(pytz.timezone(self.env.context['tz']).localize(fields.Datetime.from_string(self.start_date), is_dst=None).astimezone(pytz.utc))
```

similar but with +24 hrs

```
end_date = fields.Datetime.to_string(pytz.timezone(self.env.context['tz']).localize(fields.Datetime.from_string(self.end_date), is_dst=None).astimezone(pytz.utc) + timedelta(hours=24))
```

This was used because the passed values (self.start_date) were field.Date and therefor did not get affected by timezones, while the target stored fields were fields.Datetime and therefor stored in UTC.

start_date/end_date which are now in UTC can then be used in a self.env[''].search([])