# Django DateTimeField from form to UTC

Tags: python, django, datetime, utc

I have a small Django app with a form, wich saves some data to the DB.

Here's the form:

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    time = forms.DateTimeField()
...
```

And the view, where I save it:

```
class AccountAddIncome(View):
    def save(self, form):
        model = Model(
            time=form.cleaned_data['time']
        )
        model.save()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = SomeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            self.save(form)
            return redirect(self.success_url)
        else:
            ...
```

My problem is, that the Django admin says: *"Note: You are 1 hour ahead of server time."*
The `date` command on my Ubuntu (*the server*) says exactly the same date as my computer has.

But, when I save this object in the DB, and make the following query:

```
Model.objects.filter(time__lt=timezone.now())
```

django do not list the previously saved model for an hour. If I go to the admin, and set the time back one hour, django'll show that object.

So, my question is, what's the best practice, to manage datetime objects in django?

I want to save everything in UTC, but I cannot convert that datetime from the form to UTC.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79797/how-do-i-convert-local-time-to-utc-in-python). may help you.

Comment: In your `settings.py`, do you have `USE_TZ = True`?

Comment: Yes, `USE_TZ` is `True`, and `TIME_ZONE` is set to `'UTC'`.

Comment: To get rid of the warning `You are 1 hour ahead of server time.` I just set the `TIME_ZONE` var at settings.py

Answer (score -5):

go to settings.py of your Django project

comment timezone settings and use  TIME_ZONE = timezone.now()

```
from django.utils import timezone


TIME_ZONE = timezone.now()

# TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
# USE_I18N = True
# USE_L10N = True
# USE_TZ = True
```

Than you will never see this -  **Note: You are 1 hour ahead of server time.**