# Django DateTimeField says 'You are 5.5 hours ahead of server time.'

Tags: python, django, timezone, django-timezone

In one of my model I am storing `time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)`

But when I save the model it says `You are 5.5 hours ahead of server time.`
for example local time in my machine is `13:02` but after saving what gets stored in db is `7:16`

I got one related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26722141/django-datetimefield-from-form-to-utc) but it does not an have a satisfying answer...

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' On save, update timestamps '''
        if not self.id:
            self.time_stamp = timezone.now()
        return super(Comment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As you are 5.5 hrs ahead of server time, I am assuming, you are in India.
So put appriopriate timezone in settings.py

> TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

If somewhere else, set accordingly

Comment: What if someone else uses the app? And that user is from a different timezone?

Comment: IMO, in such situations you should store time in UTC i.e timezone unaware objects, and while displaying it to users, modify the time based on their local timezones. If you are using APIs, then its best to return the UTC UNIX timestamp and let the consumers of API decide what they want to do with it. 

If using web UI, In django templates, you can detect the timezones using `{% get_current_timezone as TIME_ZONE %}`

@0x5961736972
Read this for more info https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#get-current-timezone

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you make the following change in the settings.py file in your Django project.

[image: Change in settings.py file]

Answer (score 3):

If it is saying that you are 5.5 hours ahead of server time. It means that you are in India then set

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
```

in your setting.py file.

Or check your time zone at
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Answer (score -8):

You need to change the time zone settings on your PC and refresh. That is the only way out. I just fixed my own through that.