# Django error while posting into DateTimeField

Tags: python, angularjs, django

I am trying to post an entry into my Django model which has a `DateTimeField`. Since i am using angular on my frontend, the date format that it posts to my Django View is of the format

```
Tue Jun 30 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)
```

But Django will not allow me to post as the datetime format did not allow this format.

```
2015-05-23 18:48:08.543655
```

and it threw me this error:

```
[u"'Tue Jun 30 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]
```

So what do i use to get around this issue?

Comment: probably duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79797/how-do-i-convert-local-time-to-utc-in-python

Comment: @MaNKuR this is not a duplicate because the post you referred to is UTC time which is supported using Datetime wheras CDT is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `toUTCString()` on your `Date` instance:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toUTCString();
```

On the python side thats parsable with:

```
datetime.strptime("Tue, 22 Nov 2011 06:00:00 GMT", "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
```

Also if you're working with django forms, have a look at the [datetimefield documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#datetimefield). You can find an explanation on how to set various formats there.

Answer (score 0):

In your view, just manipulate the date given by your angular code into the proper Django datetime format.

Comment: can you tell me how do i do that? i tried datetime.strptime() but it didnt work