# How to convert local datetime into utcdatetime in Python before serialization?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, serialization

I want serialize `datetime` with `json` but before serialization I need to convert **local time** into **utc time** how can I do it if I know **tzinfo**?

```
import datetime

def some_conversion(d):
  ???

# assume that now() and utcnow() is taken in same time - this code is not valid to test it.
assert(some_conversion(datetime.datetime.now()) == datetime.datetime.utcnow())
```

I prepare some serialization function but has not idea how to solve conversion. I want to serialize `datetime` in utc format with very high speed and full precision.

```
import datetime
import json
import timeit

d = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

def date_tuple():
  x = (d.year, d.month, d.day, d.hour, d.minute, d.second, d.microsecond)
  y = json.dumps(x)
  z = json.loads(y)
  b = datetime.datetime(*z)

print timeit.timeit(date_tuple, number=1000)
```

if d != b:
    raise ValueError(d-b)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `pytz` module?

Assume you have Vladivostok time zone.

```
import pytz, datetime
local = pytz.timezone("Asia/Vladivostok")
naive_dt = datetime.datetime.now()
local_dt = local.localize(naive_dt, is_dst=None)
utc_dt = local_dt.astimezone (pytz.utc)
```

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/79797/3606603) question