# Assign a date to a time in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, websocket

A Python script running on a server in NYC receives a stream of live data from a websocket API where only the time is given, eg: `8:21:56`. The provided time is in the timezone `Asia/Chongqing` which is `UTC +08:00`. The local server is in the timezone `America/New_York` which is `UTC -05:00`.

This means that the dates in both timezones are different for 12-13 hours every day depending on daylight savings.

**Question:** Knowing that my server is in a *different timezone*, how can I find the date needed to convert the time into an appropriate datetime? Eg: If the local date on the server is `2015-12-05`, convert `8:21:56` to `2015-12-06 7:36:56.000Z` in the UTC timezone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert local time to UTC in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79797/how-do-i-convert-local-time-to-utc-in-python)

Comment: @KevinGuan In the SO question linked, the date is given. For this question, the date from the websocket stream can be different from the date in the local server, so it is not so straight forward

Comment: I think that doesn't matter because that question's accepted answer let you *set the timezone manually*. So you can set the timezone which you need covert from.

Answer (score 0):

`America/New_York` like many other timezones may have *different* utc offsets at *different* dates.

To get the *date* in one time zone (`Asia/Chongqing`) corresponding to a given *time* (`'8:21:56'`) in that time zone (`Asia/Chongqing`) assuming you know the *date* in another time zone (`America/New_York`), you should create an algorithm similar to [pytz's `.localize()` method](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~stub/pytz/devel/view/head:/src/pytz/tzinfo.py#L244) where the difficult part is to *convert local time to UTC* that is not always possible -- the rest is straightforward (if you know UTC date/time and the zone id such as `Asia/Chongqing` then it is easy (`utc_dt.astimezone(tz).date()`) to get date in `Asia/Chongqing`.

You could simplify the algorithm if you need to support only a fixed number of timezones in a given date range.