# python mktime(.timetuple()) returns different results in mac and linux

Tags: python

I noticed `time.mktime(.timetuple())` returned different time on mac and linux(ubuntu). Why this?

```
date = ['2016-07-01', '2016-07-05']

xdata = [datetime.datetime.strptime(str(s), "%Y-%m-%d") for s in date]
xdata = [time.mktime(s.timetuple()) * 1000 for s in xdata]
print xdata

# ----mac--
>> [1467356400000.0, 1467702000000.0]

#-----linux---
>> [1467345600000.0, 1467691200000.0]
```

How to return in UTC?

Comment: What does `time.mktime(time.gmtime(0))` return on each platform?  If that differs too, the platforms are set to different time zones.  `mktime()` views its input as being in "local time".  The results you're seeing differ by 3 hours.

Comment: yes, its very possible the timezones are different. How to convert from local to UTC?

Comment: @TimPeters results defers on both platforms. Linux returns `18000.0
` while Mac returns `28800.0`

Comment: Given that you really want to convert to a UTC timestamp, I marked to close this as a duplicate question - see the link I supplied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I marked to close this as a duplicate, but it's really not if you're viewing your original inputs as being in UTC to begin with.  *If* you are (it's not wholly clear), then just replace your `time.mktime` with `calendar.timegm`.

```
>>> d = datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 1)
>>> calendar.timegm(d.timetuple())
1472688000
```

Or you can do it all yourself:

```
>>> EPOCH = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)
>>> def dt2utcstamp(d):
...     return (d - EPOCH).total_seconds()
```

and then:

```
>>> dt2utcstamp(d)
1472688000.0
```

I generally do the latter, because I find it next to impossible to remember what all the goofy time-and-date functions do ;-)  But the `timedelta.total_seconds()` method doesn't exist before Python 3.2.

Or if you do view the inputs as being in local time, then the other answers apply:

[How do I convert local time to UTC in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79797/how-do-i-convert-local-time-to-utc-in-python)

### NOTE

When you ask "How to return in UTC?", you have to realize that your *original* code already did that:  timestamps are always viewed as being seconds from the epoch in UTC.  Indeed, that's why you got different results on platforms set to different time zones to begin with:  `'2016-07-01'`(with implied time `00:00:00`) is a different real-world instant depending on which time zone it's viewed as being in.

The `s.timetuple()` part doesn't care about that, but it's a primary purpose of the `time.mktime()` part to convert the local time *to* a UTC timestamp.