# datetime in Elasticsearch - How to handle timezone

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, timezone, kibana, timezone-offset

I try to index a field containing a date.

How can I index a date from a different timezone ?

I've set my elasticsearch field like so :
'requested_dt': {"type": "date", "format": "date_time_no_millis"}
'local_dt': {"type": "date", "format": "date_time_no_millis"}

I've tried to index these values (local_dt) :
(requested_dt is the current time in France)

```
IT 2016-10-27T23:46:17Z
GB 2016-10-27T22:46:19Z
```

I don't get the expected result through Kibana :

```
[local_dt]
IT October 28th 2016, 01:46:17.000
GB October 28th 2016, 00:46:19.000

[requested_dt]
IT October 27th 2016, 23:46:17.000
GB October 27th 2016, 23:46:19.000
```

So, for requested_dt, I get what I expect.

For local_dt, I don't get what I want.

I've tried to replace the Z value with the UTC offset but I'm not able to get the correct output.

Is there someone able to explain to me how to get the correct output for each timezone I want ?

Comment: you tried the date filter in `logstash`?

Comment: I did not use logstash; just tried to send values using python

Answer (score 7):

As I read(and my own experience), Kibana will index the `@timestamp` assuming they come in UTC, **and only** in format like `2018-04-23T10:45:13.899Z`. Note that we only have milliseconds and the `T` as separator and `Z` indicating UTC.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-timezone/29270/5

So, if you have a local `datetime` object, try to convert to UTC time, and format it like above.

- In case of `now()`, use `timezone.now()` of `django.utils.timezone`; or, without django, you have `datetime.datetime.utcnow()`
- If you have an `datetime()` object already, you can do:

this:

```
import pytz, datetime
local = pytz.timezone ("Europe/Paris")
local_dt = local.localize(your_datetime_object, is_dst=None)
utc_dt = local_dt.astimezone(pytz.utc)
```

(thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79797/how-do-i-convert-local-time-to-utc-in-python#answer-79877))

When you have the object, format like:

```
timeStr = datetime.strftime(your_utc_time_object, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f") # %f: microseconds, 1/10^6 seconds.
timeStr = timeStr[:-3] # delete the trailing 3 digits, convert to milliseconds
toInsert["@timestamp"] = nowStr + "Z" # add 'Z' at last
```

Answer (score 4):

For the benefit of anyone coming here via Google search like me, you **cannot** append a [military time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones) letter to the end of the timestamp and have Elasticsearch recognize it.

I thought this would be the case since it recognizes and outputs the "Z" at the end of a UTC timestamp, so I appended "R" to my own timestamps to signify they came from UTC-5. Here's what they would look like next to each other:

```
"2020-04-09T07:35:15.100Z"  # parsed as UTC
"2020-04-09T07:35:15.100R"  # illegal argument exception
```

However, none of the built-in formats would recognize this additional letter; you *must* either specify the time offset like so

```
"2020-04-09T07:35:15.100-0500"
"2020-04-09T07:35:15.100-05:00"
```

or specify the timezone in your pipeline processor

```
{
  "pipeline": {
    "processors": [
      {
        "date": {
          "field": "raw_date",
          "formats": ["ISO8601"],
          "timezone": "America/New_York"
        }
      }]
  }
}
```