# python timezone GMT conversion

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I have this date format:

```
Sat Apr 14 21:05:23 GMT-00:00 2018
```

I want to use `datetime` to store this data.

`datetime.datetime.strptime(dateString, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y').timetuple()`

What is the date/time format for GMT?  The [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) doesn't have GMT.

Comment: What document are you referring to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79797/how-do-i-convert-local-time-to-utc-in-python ?

Comment: here is the link to the document:https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Handling timezones is always a bit confusing.  In your example, you were not specific in your needs as it relates to the timezone.

**Fixed timezone offset:**

One way to read what you wrote is that the timezone information in your string is always `GMT-00:00`. If the timezone is always the same, then it is a simple matter to build a `strptime` string as:

```
dt.datetime.strptime(date, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S GMT-00:00 %Y')
```

This makes no effort to interpret the timezone, since it is fixed. This will give you timezone naive `datetime`.  And since your example immediately converted the `datetime` to a `timetuple`, I assume this is the result you wanted.

**To test:**

```
>>> date = "Sat Apr 14 21:05:23 GMT-00:00 2018"
>>> print(dt.datetime.strptime(date, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S GMT-00:00 %Y'))
2018-04-14 21:05:23
```

**Interpreting the timezone offset:**

If you have non-GMT timezones in your timestamps, and want to preserve the information you can do:

```
def convert_to_datetime(datetime_string):
    # split on spaces
    ts = datetime_string.split()

    # remove the timezone
    tz = ts.pop(4)

    # parse the timezone to minutes and seconds
    tz_offset = int(tz[-6] + str(int(tz[-5:-3]) * 60 + int(tz[-2:])))

    # return a datetime that is offset
    return dt.datetime.strptime(' '.join(ts), '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y') - \
        dt.timedelta(minutes=tz_offset)
```

This function will take your time string and make use of the `UTC` offset. (eg. `-00:00`).  It will parse the timezone information out of the string and then add the resulting minutes and seconds back into the `datetime` to make it `UTC` relative.

**To test:**

```
>>> print(convert_to_datetime("Sat Apr 14 21:05:23 GMT-00:00 2018"))
2018-04-14 21:05:23

>>> print(convert_to_datetime("Sat Apr 14 21:05:23 PST-08:00 2018"))
2018-04-15 05:05:23
```

**Timezone aware:**

The above codes return a `UTC` relative timezone naive `datetime`.  It if you need a timezone aware `datetime`, then you can do that with:

```
datetime.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC))
```

**To test:**

```
>>> import pytz
>>> print(convert_to_datetime("Sat Apr 14 21:05:23 GMT-00:00 2018").replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC))
2018-04-14 21:05:23+00:00
```

Comment: In my case, looks like I always have GMT-00:00.  Thank you so much for the answer.  My problem is solved.