# unbale to convert localtime to utc using python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to convert local date time to UTC format but I am unable to convert Please let me know how to get required output using following input

**Input    :  2008-09-17 10:45:00 PM**

**Output   :  2008-09-17 17:15:00 PM**

**required output:  1715UTC**

```
  from datetime import *
  from dateutil import *
  from dateutil.tz import tz


  utc_zone = tz.gettz('UTC')
  local_zone = tz.gettz('Asia/kolkata')

  utc_zone = tz.tzutc()
  local_zone = tz.tzlocal()

   # Convert time string to datetime

  local_time = datetime.strptime("2008-09-17 10:45:00 PM", '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p')

  local_time = local_time.replace(tzinfo=local_zone)

  utc_time = local_time.astimezone(utc_zone)

  utc_string = utc_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %p')
  print utc_string
```

Answer (score 0):

See this:
[How do I convert local time to UTC in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79797/how-do-i-convert-local-time-to-utc-in-python)

It shows how to format the time as per your requirements.

Comment: required output: 1715UTC   not getting output in this format