# How to get the difference between a datetime in UTC and utcnow in Python

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, utc

I've got a datetime as a string (`2016-12-31 23:59`), from which I know it was defined in UTC. I now want to get the timedelta using Python. The machine I'm doing this on will normally be in the CEST time zone (`Europe/Amsterdam`), but this might not always be the case and therefore I don't want to hardcode this time zone in the code.

For local timezones this would work great:

```
date_str = '2016-12-31 23:59'
print datetime.now() - datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

this obviously isn't correct though, but changing it to use `utcnow()` is also not correct:

```
print datetime.utcnow() - datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

This doesn't work correctly because now the datetime resulting from strptime is in the timezone of the machine this code is running on, while the utcnow() is in UTC.

I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/79877/1650012), but that assumes you know the timezone of the machine the code is running on, which I don't.

Is there a way that I can add the UTC timezone to the `datetime` object which I get from `datetime.strptime()` so that I can compare it with `utcnow()`? All tips are welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is actually fine. Your mistake is in this assumption: "the datetime resulting from `strptime` is in the timezone of the machine this code is running on."

`datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')` will produce a *naive* datetime representing a time that you said was in UTC.

`datetime.utcnow()` will produce a *naive* datetime representing the current time in UTC.

So the difference will be accurate.