# Python: Formatting time for influxdb

Tags: python, datetime, influxdb

I want to input a date/time into influx db from python but not sure how to do this.  Python code `datetime.datetime.now()`  currently gives out a format like this : 2018-06-25 13:59:36.698000.

I know this format is accepted by influx "1529932431998" which is "2018-06-25T13:13:51.998Z" or "0x1643714427e".  Any ideas how i can get python to give me 11 digit number from python?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need `epoch` time.

**Try:**

```
import datetime
import time
print( time.mktime(datetime.datetime.now().timetuple()) )
```

**Output:**

```
1529932959.0
```

Comment: just read up on epoch, its UNIX time which makes sense since influx is built on linux.

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://www.influxdata.com/blog/start-python-influxdb/), they do it like this:

```py
Point('example')
.field("temperature",42.0)
.time(int(dt.timestamp()))
```

If you send the data as a `dict()` (not using the influx `Point` class), you can convert it also to a string. Influx expects UTC-Time in Milliseconds:

```py
dt = datetime.now()
influx_time = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") # or dt.isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')
data['time'] = influx_time
data['measurment'] = 'example'
data['field'] = 'temperature'
data['value'] = 42.0
...
write_api.write(bucket=bucket, org=org, record=data)
```

Most likely, you will need to attach the **Timezone** as well to get it right, e.g.  `influx_time = influx_time + "+02" # UTC+02:00`. Or better use the [`pytz`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79797/how-to-convert-local-time-string-to-utc) module, which helps handling nasty stuff like summer/wintertime

Hope that helps somebody. Took me a while to figure out..