# Python date object Convert to UTC timestamp at midnight

Tags: python, datetime

I have python date object like

`datetime.date(2020, 3, 29)`  # d1, django DateField in database

Now i want to get UTC timestamp of that date object `d1` at midnight

I searched a lot but nothing works.

I tried

```
d2 = datetime.combine(d1, datetime.min.time())
d2.timestamp() // This is localtimezone i want in UTC
```

Not sure why i need to add time

Comment: use `datetime.utcnow()` for UTC time

Comment: @Mohsen that will only give me today , what if its some other date? can i do d1.utcnow()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert local time string to UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79797/how-to-convert-local-time-string-to-utc)

Comment: @Prudhvi i tried all those , too complex to understand whats going on there

Comment: the datetime objects in your database, in what timezone are they in? UTC?

Comment: @MrFuppes its only dateField not datetime Django date field

Comment: alright, I tried to provide a not too complicated answer below. working with date and time can be confusing, but stay on it. I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/10197418) is worth having a look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your date object `d` is in UTC, you could simply add midnight time (00:00:00) and timezone info UTC and then apply `timestamp()` method to get the desired timestamp. Example:

```
import datetime as dt

d = dt.date(2020, 3, 29)
ts_utc = dt.datetime.combine(d, dt.time(0,0,0), tzinfo=dt.timezone.utc).timestamp()
print(ts_utc)
# 1585440000.0

check = dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts_utc)
print(check)
# 2020-03-29 00:00:00
```

Note: it is important to set the timezone, otherwise, the `timestamp()` method assumes that the input is in the timezone that the machine you run this code on is set to!