# How can i convert a python local datetime object to utc

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time, utc

I have `due_by` as a local `datetime` object the following solutions isn't working for me!

```
due_by = float(due_by.strftime("%s"))
due_by = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(due_by)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert local time string to UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79797/how-to-convert-local-time-string-to-utc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timezone

# Datetime to timestamp
t = datetime.now()
due_by = t.timestamp()
# 1600261731.016313
print(due_by)

# Timestamp to datetime
due_by = datetime.fromtimestamp(due_by, tz=timezone.utc)
# 2020-09-16 13:08:51.016313+00:00
print(due_by)
```

Comment: you can do `datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)` straight away.

Comment: How does this with a passed in datetime value instead of "now()"?