# Not able to change IST to UTC

Tags: python, django

Current IST (Asia/Kolkata) is 5:23 PM and UTC is 11:53 AM same day.
I wanted to convert IST to UTC. I tried following:

```
from dateutil import tz
from datetime import datetime

from_zone = tz.gettz('IST') # also tried tz.gettz('Asia/Kolkata')
to_zone = tz.gettz('UTC')

t = '2023-06-04 05:23'
t = datetime.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
t = t.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
t = t.astimezone(to_zone)
print(t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
```

Above still prints `'2023-06-04 05:23'`. That is no time zone change happened. Why is this so?

Here is the screenshot of run:
[image]

Comment: I can not reproduce this, locally it prints: `2023-06-03 23:53`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Added a screenshot of run

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Earlier I did not have line `t = '2023-06-04 05:23'`. Was that an issue?

Comment: Ended up following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63920772/6357916) approach.