# How to change the timezone?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

So the default time for Python is London, but I am trying to change it to EDT/New York time. This is what I did:

```
import datetime

time = datetime.datetime.now()
print('{}:{}'.format(time.strftime('%I'), time.strftime('%M')))
```

I want to make it EDT time, so I looked up ways to do it, but every time i got something different and it wouldn't work. I am very confused.

P.S I'm using onlineGDB as a compiler, so some things don't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert local time string to UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79797/how-to-convert-local-time-string-to-utc)

Comment: "*the default time for Python is London*" - that is incorrect; by default, Python will use the local time your OS is configured to use.

Comment: @Tomerikoo: the linked dupe for me seems to be confusing to newcomers (and outdated in some places); + the OP just wanted to get time in a specific time zone, not UTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [now classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) has a tz argument which you should use to set the appropriate timezone; e.g.

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.tz import gettz

print(datetime.now(gettz('America/New_York')))
>>> 2020-09-28 02:56:19.063552-04:00
```

This code also works fine if you use the gdb online Python debugger.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Is it possible to assign the    datetime.now(gettz('America/New_York'))        to a variable, then get the time in 12-hour clock? That is what I was initially trying to do.

Comment: OK I played with it a little bit, and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pytz?

```
from pytz import timezone
EDT = timezone('America/New_York')
time = EDT.localize(datetime.datetime.now())

print('{}:{}'.format(time.strftime('%I'), time.strftime('%M')))
```

Comment: I have tried some variations of it. Also, the code you wrote still displays the London time. It may just be GitHub, or maybe I'm just using it wrong. I haven't been coding for too long, maybe around a couple months.

Comment: please note the [pytz deprecation](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/). for now, there's `dateutil`; until in Python 3.9 you'll have `zoneinfo`.